# How to use subprocess on the GPU for batch inferencing?

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I am using YOLOv4 to train an object detection model on Colab. This  is what I use to run tests on the test set:

```
#/test has images that we can test our detector on
test_folder = "/content/logorec/Worlds-2020-Logos/"
test_images = [f for f in os.listdir(test_folder) if f.endswith('.png')]
import random
img_path = ''

for i in range(0, len(test_images)):
  img_path = test_folder + test_images[i];
  !./darknet detect cfg/custom-yolov4-detector.cfg backup/custom-yolov4-detector_last.weights {img_path} -dont-show
  imShow('predictions.jpg')
```

As you can see, the problem is that it tests 1 file at a time. This is highly inefficient for a very large test set. Is there a way I can run inference in batch (concurrently) instead of sequentially? I currently have access to a Tesla V100 GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You have to load all test images via path into [tf.dataset.Dataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) object. I don't know where you get YoloV4 but I think it must provide a function to read the whole dataset object at once. Try to open file `darknet` to find it

Comment: Could you elaborate? What do I do after loading the dataset?

Comment: `darknet` command I assume it's a Python script/package. There should be a function in it that can load a dataset. You open it then in your notebook you call that function.